# If comparison with subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement

I don't understand why the code bellow is executed when the value of 
strArray(0) is Subscript out of range. My booleanVariable changes to true and I don't want that.

```
If Left(strArray(0), 3) = "Usu" Then
     booleanVariable = True    
End If
```

Comment: I don't understand how the title refers to the question... is `0` out of range for `strArray`? If so, possibly you have an `On Error Resume Next` that could cause the code to blow through the `If` statement?

Comment: It executes the if statement even using the on error resume next.

Comment: If you know that `strArray(0)` is out of range, why write that in the code? If you're just looking for the first element of the array, you could use `strArray(Lbound(strArray))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the array(0) is not empty before trying to do string manipulation

```
sub t
If Initialized(strArray) Then ' is array setup
    If strArray(0) <> "" Then ' if array has value
        If Left(strArray(0), 3) = "Usu" Then
             booleanVariable = True
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No value in array"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Array not setup"
End If
end sub

Function Initialized(val) As Boolean
On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim i

    If Not IsArray(val) Then GoTo exitRoutine

    i = UBound(val)

    Initialized = True
exitRoutine:
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9 'Subscript out of range
            GoTo exitRoutine
        Case Else
            Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
                "Error in Initialized()"
    End Select
    Debug.Assert False
    Resume
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't work since strArray(0) = <Subscript out of range>

Comment: try above now. can you do ? strArray(0) in the immediate window?